# Open Web/URL through app

Tags: java-me, midlet

i'm developing J2ME.
Could you mind helping me to find out whats wrong with this code:

```
HttpConnection c = null;

    try {
        c = (HttpConnection)Connector.open("http://www.mysite.com",Connector.READ_WRITE, true);
        c.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET); //default
        is = c.openInputStream(); // transition to connected!
            int ch = 0;
        for(int ccnt=0; ccnt < 150; ccnt++) { // get the title.
            ch = is.read();
            if (ch == -1){
                break;
            }
                sb.append((char)ch);
        }
    }   
    catch (IOException x){
        x.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        try     {
            is.close();
            c.close();
        } catch (IOException x){
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

i'm trying open website through my app, thanks before :)

Comment: Did you want to show the site content on screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To open a URL in J2ME you do the following in a non-system thread:

[`MIDlet.platformRequest("http://www.mysite.com/");`](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/midlet/MIDlet.html#platformRequest%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: ok ( +1 for it ), as i said AFAIK, thanks for this information, i didn't know this part :)

Comment: @funkybro where i put the code?
could you mind giving me an example code implementation?